# PDO::quote() for SQL Server mis-quotes strings containing ASCII NUL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm trying to insert ASCII NUL characters (`\0` aka `U+0000`) into an SQL Server database from PHP, using pdo_sqlsrv.  This is a requirement for handling PHP serialized strings, which contain NUL characters to represent private/protected variables.

However, there is something about PDO::quote() which is breaking the strings.

Code to reproduce (replace `DBNAME`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with appropriate values):

```
<?php

try {
    $dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAME';
    $user = 'USERNAME';
    $pass = 'PASSWORD';

    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$str = "XX\0XX";

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

print("Original: " . str_replace("\0", "{NUL}", $str) . "\n");
$str = $connection->quote($str);
print("Quoted:   " . str_replace("\0", "{NUL}", $str) . "\n");

?>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Original: XX{NUL}XX
Quoted:   'XX{NUL}XX'
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Original: XX{NUL}XX
Quoted:   'XX'{NUL}{NUL}a
```

Can anyone explain this odd behaviour and - more importantly - explain how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**

It appears that the final character is random, as on a subsequent run it was an `e`.  This implies some form of memory access error, e.g. reading past the end of the string.  Maybe a bug in the pdo_sqlsrv implementation?

Comment: Wouldn't there be no need to use `PDO::quote` if you use prepared statements?

Comment: [***If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.***](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: Prepared statement may or may not fix the problem.  I haven't tested it, but I guess it depends at what level the problem is occurring.  Either way, they are not a solution in this case, due to implementation of the DBAL (which, by the way, guarantees correct escaping, providing that `quote() ` works as expected).

Comment: `str_replace()` is a single-byte function. If you are using UTF-8 it might actually get on the way of diagnostics. What do you get with `var_dump(bin2hex($str))`?

Comment: There are no multi-byte characters in my test-case.  Just the letter `X` and the ASCII NUL character.

Comment: What part of this question warranted a downvote!?  Downvoting without commenting is pretty shitty and unhelpful.

Comment: Er, sorry, I think it was me (not sure how it happened). I can't undo the vote until the question gets edited so I'll do a bogus edit.

Comment: No problem!  :-)

Comment: If this is a bug, as suggested in the answer, it can be reported here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: @miken32 - Good suggestion.  Issue logged here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain this odd behaviour...

It appears that this is a bug in the pdo_sqlsrv extension (and, probably, in the equivalent function in the non-PDO sqlsrv extension).

I logged the issue in the extension's issue tracker ([ticket #538](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/538)) and the developers have confirmed that they can replicate the problem and that it is a bug that needs fixing.

> ...and - more importantly - explain how to resolve it?

The solution we have implemented is to detect this situation and rewrite the string to remove any NUL characters:

```
try {
    $dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBNAME';
    $user = 'USERNAME';
    $pass = 'PASSWORD';

    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection error: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$str = "XX\0XX";

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

print("Original: " . str_replace("\0", "{NUL}", $str) . "\n");
$str = safeQuote($str, $connection);
print("Quoted:   " . str_replace("\0", "{NUL}", $str) . "\n");

function safeQuote($str, $connection) {
// Special handling of ASCII NUL characters, which cause breakages.
// This appears to be due to a bug in the pdo_sqlsrv driver.
// For performance reasons, we only do this for strings that contain \0.
    if (is_string($str) && strpos($str, "\0") !== false) {
        $arrParts = explode("\0", $str);
        foreach ($arrParts as $Key => $Part) {
            $arrParts[$Key] = $connection->quote($Part);
        }
        $str = implode(" + CHAR(0) + ", $arrParts);
    }
// Otherwise, prepare the quoted string in the standard way.
    else {
        $str = $connection->quote($str);
    }

    return $str;
}

?>
```

This outputs the following, which - as far as I can see - results in a correct insert within SQL Server:

```
Original: XX{NUL}XX
Quoted:   'XX' + CHAR(0) + 'XX'
```

#### UPDATE: March 2017

The bug has been fixed in [SQLSRV/5.2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2018/03/27/microsoft-drivers-5-2-0-for-php-for-sql-server-released/).

Answer (score 1):

Running a slightly modified version of your test code in my 32-bit SQLSRV/3.2 set-up under PHP/5.6.21 showed a curious behaviour:

```php
$str = "XX\0XX";
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    printf("0x%s -> 0x%s\n", bin2hex($str), bin2hex($connection->quote($str)));
    printf("0x%s -> 0x%s\n", bin2hex($str), bin2hex($connection->quote($str)));
}
```

```
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000005
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000005
0x5858005858 -> 0x2758582700b72b
0x5858005858 -> 0x2758582700b72b
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000306
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000306
0x5858005858 -> 0x2758582700b72b
0x5858005858 -> 0x2758582700b72b
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000005
0x5858005858 -> 0x27585827000005
```

Actual bytes change on each run.

My findings:

- Results are coherent within session but change randomly across connections
- The `CharacterSet` connection option (now shown here) has no influence
- There're several bugfixes in the github repository regarding emulated prepares

So it all points to a bug in the library. I've tried latest stable release ([v4.3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2017/07/13/microsoft-drivers-v4-3-0-for-php-for-sql-server-released/) under 32-bit PHP/7.1.9) and it's still there (though, at least on my system, results are still arbitrary but not random).

Whether bug of feature, I'd say that `PDO::quote()` is not binary safe under SQLSRV. If the underlying framework does not allow prepared statements, you'll possibly need to consider [converting to hex](http://php.net/bin2hex) and sending as (unquoted) hexadecimal literal, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (0x5858005858);
```

Comment: Do you think the issue is that it's not binary safe, or do you think this is specifically an issue with NUL characters (which are often used as string terminators in Windows applications)?  Can you think of a way we could test this?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: Well, it's been fixed in the newer releases of the extension, so it is a bit of a moot question.  I've upvoted the answer, because it is a good example of how to investigate/demonstrate the problem, even though it didn't provide a direct resolution.

Answer (score -1):

1. As `\` can be used in the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) statement you need to add slashes before you quote thereby escaping your original slash.
2. Rather than using `PDO::quote` make use of prepared statements as is mentioned in the [`PDO::quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) documentation.

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.

**Live Example**

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4591c8b7f7b9255614d31d0ca1f38806f8e1920)

**Output**

```
<?php
$pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null);

$str = "XX\0XX";

print($pdo->quote(addSlashes($str))); <----> 'XX\0XX'

?>
```

Comment: `str_replace()` is only being used to provide debugging output and is not part of the problem.  Prepared statements are not relevant to this question, as per my comment, above.  I don't think you understand my question.

Comment: Thanks, but that still won't work: `SELECT CHARINDEX('\', 'XX\0XX');` returns `3`, meaning SQL Server treats `\0` as two characters `\ ` and `0`, not as a single NUL character.  (Note that you get the same result for National strings: `SELECT CHARINDEX(N'\', N'XX\0XX');`).

Comment: @HappyDog I'll try do some more research but I'm not too sure to be honest, never really used `PDO::quote` so I've never had to face this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `PDO::quote()` is implemented by the driver, thus testing it in SQLite is unlikely to shed light on SQL Server issues.